# Is it possible to have an .NET Core Console app be interactively running with a background ASP.NET Web running?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I would like my .NET Core Console app to have an interactive user session in the command line.

Is it possible to have this, while offering both client and server web sockets at the same time?

In other words if I type echo in on the console, I want to use an event to communicate with the website thread internally.  Is this possible? (supported?)

Comment: Why?  What value does the provide instead of providing an API via HTTP?

Comment: I'm making a .NET Bitcoin client redo.  This means a XAML + RPC listener.  For this first round I'm trying to keep it simple with Console + RPC, where RPC = {WebSockets | Core API | SignalR }. @ErikPhilips

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  [Something like this?](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/invoking-web-application-from-console-application-net-core-via-command-prompt/)

Comment: I'll need the Main thread for UX in both Console and XAML use cases.  Have any thoughts (risks) about putting  hostBuilder.Run();  in a Task?